# In Rstudio's auto complete, how to show the first argument of a function when using dplyr::mutate?

Tags: r, rstudio, dplyr

It's nice to see that rstudio understands pipes and doesn't display the first argument in autocomplete when using a pipe `%>%`. But this is causing a trouble with `dplyr::mutate`. See for example the screen shot below

Sample code:

```
iris %>% 
    mutate(gsub("a","A",Species))
```

[image]

I would like to see `gsub`'s argument `pattern` also in the auto-complete suggestion when the cursor is just after `gsub(`.

Comment: This has been fixed in more recent versions of RStudio.

Comment: Pressing the Delete button for this question returns this message: "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in more recent versions of RStudio.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you type in the opening parentheses after "gsub", I see the entire method signature pop up like this:

[image]

However, when I try the tab autocomplete in the way you suggested, this is what I see:

[image]

Your screenshot cut off what I think is a crucial part of the picture here: if you look at the bottom of the argument list, you'll see "Sepal.Length" mentioned. I'm not sure how, but I think the implementation of the piping operator might be responsible. It was only introduced in 2014, so it's not implausible that there are some lingering bugs. If you want to get the most accurate representation of the arguments, I would suggest looking at the pop up (what you see in my first screenshot) instead of the autocomplete list.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have a popup when I type `iris%>% mutate(gsub())` on Rstudio Version 0.99.467 on Debian Linux. I see the auto-complete list directly.