# Auto-complete when using RStudio

Tags: r, autocomplete, rstudio

I have recently started using R and learned about Hadley's ggplot2 and other packages. Now, the good part is that his packages don't require us to write datasetname$xyz (or if we use "with" or "attach"), but the bad part is that R-Studio's auto-complete doesn't recognize the column names. Some of the columns I am working with have long names, and I tend to make mistakes while typing them.

Is there any solution that would let me use Hadley's package or "with"/"attach" without losing auto-complete feature?

I am a beginner so I would appreciate any thoughts.

For instance, here's how my data looks like:

```
acctnum gender state   zip zip3 first last book_ nonbook_ total_ purch child youth cook do_it refernce art geog buyer
1   10001      M    NY 10605  106    49   29   109      248    357    10     3     2    2     0        1   0    2    no
2   10002      M    NY 10960  109    39   27    35      103    138     3     0     1    0     1        0   0    1    no
3   10003      F    PA 19146  191    19   15    25      147    172     2     0     0    2     0        0   0    0    no
4   10004      F    NJ 07016  070     7    7    15      257    272     1     0     0    0     0        1   0    0    no
5   10005      F    NY 10804  108    15   15    15      134    149     1     0     0    1     0        0   0    0    no
6   10006      F    NY 11366  113     7    7    15       98    113     1     0     1    0     0        0   0    0   yes
```

Now, if I use ttest using $,

[using $ sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nol3d.png)

on the contrary, if I use ggplot2,
[using ggplot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENVZO.png)

As you can see, I don't see any of the column names.

I did find similar post here ([In Rstudio's auto complete, how to show the first argument of a function when using dplyr::mutate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205848/in-rstudios-auto-complete-how-to-show-the-first-argument-of-a-function-when-us)). However, this post talks about function arguments and not variables. I am good with function arguments, but have issues typing the variable names.

Thanks

Comment: Can you submit this as a feature request to http://support.rstudio.com?

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I wasn't sure that this is a bug or my ignorance. I am new to R, and RStudio. It has been only about a week since I downloaded RStudio...